# Cannot find Interface Builder Preview in Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

According to Apple's official documentation titled "Previewing localizations"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/previewing-localizations/#

"For Interface Builder, you can preview localizations any time during development by choosing localizations including pseudolanguages in the preview. You don’t need to build and run your app to see the preview."

However, this functionality seems to have been removed in Xcode 15. "Preview" is not available in the Editor option menu in Interface Builder.

[image: Editor option menu in Interface Builder in Xcode 15]

Compared to what's available before:

[image: Editor option menu in Interface Builder in Xcode earlier version]